# "ls" with regex multiple times

Tags: regex, ls

I am trying to do next two commands on one line:

```
ls -lh  /etc/pki/tls/certs/dom*
ls -lh  /etc/pki/tls/certs/cen*
```

I tried something like next but it does not work:

```
ls -lh  /etc/pki/tls/certs/cen*|dom*
ls -lh  /etc/pki/tls/certs/[cen*|dom*]
ls -lh  /etc/pki/tls/certs/{cen*|dom*}
```

Is next the only way?:

```
ls -lh  /etc/pki/tls/certs/cen*  &&  ls -lh  /etc/pki/tls/certs/dom*
```

Comment: Sorry, I forget to add that bash is not in location needed. What I am trying to do is:`ls -lh /etc/pki/tls/certs/[dom*|cen*]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two are equivalent:

```
ls -lh /etc/pki/tls/certs/dom* /etc/pki/tls/certs/cen*

ls -lh /etc/pki/tls/certs/{dom,cen}*
```

Answer (score 1):

try this, it's very simple

```
ls -lh dom* cen*
```

Comment: Yes, but it does not work if bash is not in the location needed.